# not able to connect to the group owner through client during Wifi P2p connection

Tags: android, client, ping, file-transfer, wifi-direct

I have wrote the code for ping async task but while executing it is taking only group owner ip address and not of host in the InetSocketAddress function

the code is as below

```java
public static class PingTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {

        private Context context;
        public PingTask()
        {

        }
        public PingTask(Context context)
        {
            this.context=context;
        }


        //private String grp_address=WifiBroadcastReceiver.address;



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //super.onPreExecute();
            Log.d("Method","******In pre Execute");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... voids) {
            String gp=voids[0];

            Socket socket=new Socket();
            int port=9990;
            int Socket_Timeout=500000;
            try {
                Log.d("GROUP OWNER ADDRESS","#########"+gp);
                Log.d("Receive Activity", "Opening client socket - ");
                socket.bind(null);

                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.49.1"),9990), Socket_Timeout);
                Log.d("Receive Activity", "Client socket - " + socket.isConnected());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Receive Activity", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {
                if (socket != null) {
                    if (socket.isConnected()) {
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // Give up
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return gp;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            if(s!=null)
            {
                Log.d("Post Method","*****In post Execute");
                Log.d("Post Method","*****In post Execute"+s);
            }
```

And it is giving below error

```
2019-11-24 16:24:57.606 26016-26016/com.example.photo_sharing D/GROUP OWNER ADDRESS: 192.168.49.1
2019-11-24 16:24:57.607 26016-26016/com.example.photo_sharing D/IP ADDRESS: 192.168.0.2
2019-11-24 16:24:57.608 26016-26016/com.example.photo_sharing D/Method: ******In pre Execute
2019-11-24 16:24:57.609 26016-26016/com.example.photo_sharing D/Receive Activity: Opening client socket
2019-11-24 16:24:57.610 26016-26053/com.example.photo_sharing D/GROUP OWNER ADDRESS: #########192.168.49.1
2019-11-24 16:24:57.610 26016-26053/com.example.photo_sharing D/Receive Activity: Opening client socket - 
2019-11-24 16:24:57.614 26016-26053/com.example.photo_sharing E/Receive Activity: failed to connect to /192.168.49.1 (port 9990) from /192.168.49.1 (port 44461) after 500000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

Comment: `D/IP ADDRESS: 192.168.0.2` That is the ip-address of who? And how did you obtain it? (

Comment: `failed to connect to /192.168.49.1 (port 9990) from /192.168.49.1 (port 44461)` The same ip! Where is your app running?

Comment: `after 500000ms:` In your loglines it's only 14 ms.

Comment: Please remove the `ping`and `file-transfer` tag.  The problem is not about them.